# Repeating +CMGS - first ok, then not working

Tags: sms, gsm, modem

I'm using this code to talk to a stock GSM modem... (Telit/Simcom etc)

```
// ------------------------------
  sprintf(localbuf, "AT+CMGS=\"%s\"\r", recipient);
  Serial1.write(localbuf);   // initiate the SMS conversation
  if (waitFor(5000, "> ", "ERR")) {
    sprintf(localbuf, "%s%c", textMessage, CTRL_Z);
    Serial1.write(localbuf);  // send the message body
    //... I wait for the +CMGS: response here - all good
  } else {
    Serial.write("\r\n-- SMS >PROMPT FAIL --");
    retval = false;
  }
  ... and move on
```

The first message - no problem - it works fine.
If I do other things and come back to send another - no problem.
Including other modem conversations (CSQ, CCLK etc)

But if I try to send more than one message fairly close together (in a loose loop), the second +CMGS request fails to return the '>' prompt... ?

Any thoughts.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is a little messy. Can you add the failing code with the loop you're using?

Comment: I strongly object to closing this question as "too broad". The question asks specific about one problem, and gives all required details.

Comment: I am delighted to see several things done right with regards to AT command handling: terminating a AT command line with just `\r`, reading and parsing responses from the modem, and waiting with the sms payload until the prompt is given. Excellent.

Comment: Having said that, I just want to point out that the prompt is not just the two characters `"> "`. The 27.005 specification says "the TA shall send a four character sequence `<CR><LF><greater_than><space>` ... after that text can be entered from TE to ME/TA". Maybe this is implicitly covered by splitting input on line breaks in the waitFor function, but if not you can improve the correctness of your code by waiting for those four characters in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED -** Well - so far so good (**SFSG**?)

I discovered that ***if I hold-off for a second AFTER the final CMGS:... .OK*** is received - the following messages work as expected.

So I guess that 'OK' really isn't OK (!), no matter what testing or polling I had tried earlier - the modem simply isn't ready until it's ready.

Thanks for reading.   I hope this helps someone else.

EDIT: The data sheet quotes 20mS between sequential commands, but it's more like 200mS inworst cases...